# Normalizing data over a distribution

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a `list` `X` containg the data performed by different users `N` so the the number of the user is `i=0,1,....,N-1`. Each entry `Xi` has a different length.
I want to normalize the value of each user `Xi` over the global dataset `X`.

This is what I am doing. First of all I create a `1D` list containing all the data, so:

```
tmp = list()
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    tmp.extend(X[i])
```

then I convert it to an array and I remove outliers and `NaN`.

```
A = np.array(tmp)
A = A[~np.isnan(A)] #remove NaN
tr = np.percentile(A,95)
A = A[A < tr]  #remove outliers
```

and then I create the histogram of this dataset

```
p, x = np.histogram(A, bins=10) # bin it into n = N/10 bins
```

finally I normalize the value of each users over the histogram I created, so:

```
Xn  = list()
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    tmp = np.array(X[i])
    tmp = tmp[tmp < tr]
    tmp = np.histogram(tmp, x)
    Xn.append(append(tmp[0]/sum(tmp[0]))
```

My data set is very large and this process could take a while. I am wondering if there is e a better way to do that or a package.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of the input as well as the desired output?

Comment: I tried to change the descirption

Comment: I imagine the slowest parts of your process are the two loops, `for i in range...` so that's where I would focus on optimizing. Have you considered using `pandas`?  If you can provide a sample of the input data, your `list X` then it will be easier to make a recommendation that will give you the desired output that would take less time. Are you trying to get the histogram so that you can graph it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For large datasets, avoid converting between native Python `list` and NumPy `array` objects as much as possible.  Look at the `np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt` functions.  They may help you go from saved files of your data to NumPy arrays without having to make any Python lists at all.  But suppose you do have a Python list.  You shouldn't have to convert all of the data to a NumPy array, and then later convert each users's data to an array separately.  I would try something like this, assuming that `np.loadtxt` doesn't work for you:

   ```
   data_lengths = [len(Xi) for Xi in X]
   num_users = len(X)
   max_length = max(data_lengths)
   all_data = np.zeros(shape = (num_users, max_length), dtype = 'int')

   for row, Xi in enumerate(X):
       row_length = len(Xi)
       all_data[row, 0:row_length] = Xi
   ```

   From then on, every operation on your data should be an operation on a NumPy array instead of on a Python list.  The way I wrote it, it assumes your data are integers, and also that 0 can never occur as a real data point.  You can modify the `dtype` and offset of the call to `np.zeros` accordingly to meet the requirements of your particular data.

   This approach will only be good if each user has a number of data points that is not *too* different from the number for the other users.  Other wise representing your data as a full matrix will be memory inefficient.
2. Use `dtype`s.  If your data are non-negative integers, for example, then `np.bincount()` will be much faster than `np.histogram`, for example.  Actually, if your data are integers, then you could probably just use `collections.Counter()` to make your histograms in native Python, which could also save time.